# Magento 2 - how to update attribute values with rest api (curl)

Tags: magento2, rest-api

```
$ch = curl_init("92.19.109.89/index.php/rest/V1/products/".$productId);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
//var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));
$result = json_decode($result, 1);
```

How to add data field ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace your site url instead of `http://127.0.0.1/testmagento`.

```
    <?php
    $productData = '{
        "product": {
        "extension_attributes": {
          "stock_item": {
            "qty": "20",
            "is_in_stock": true
          }
        }
        }
        }';

$url = "http://127.0.0.1/testmagento/index.php/rest/all/V1/products/t-shirt";
$token = "8mc3cad6dsc0ce74m1kyfn7iyvbpc7a7";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $productData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " .$token));
    $result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
    print_r($result);
    exit();
    ?>
```